# what is the work flow criteria for it and how to schedule email alert for it

Tags: workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have a new lead.if the lead status is not equal to "qualified" within 5days from the lead created date, then on the 5th day a notification email will go to mr A.

Answer (score 0):

See [Time-Dependent Action to Your Workflow Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&language=en_US)
[image]

1. The workflow rule criteria will be Lead Status Not Equal To Qualified.
2. You need to add a time dependent action, which will be executed on 5th day (4 days After Lead Created Date). This will evaulate the rule criteria on 5th day after Lead Created Date.
3. You need to add workflow action to send Email Alert to Mr.A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow 3 steps to create 'Time Dependent Workflow' Rule:

**1) Create Rule as per below Screenshot :**

[image]

**2) Set Workflow Action :**

[image]

**3) Set Time Dependent Workflow Action :**

[image]

- Don't forget to Activate the Workflow. :-)